# Language accepted by a RAM

Tags: computability

Show that any language accepted by a RAM can be accepted by a RAM without indirect addressing.

Could you give me some hints what I could do??

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Are you familiar with the model of Turing Machines, and how they simulate RAM machines?

Comment: try starting with the definition of both. maybe revise this with that